# ¿Se puede imprimir un .txt desde Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quería saber si es posible una vez escrito un fichero .txt de la siguiente manera en Android Studio:

```
OutputStreamWriter fichero = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("fichero.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
fichero.append("Lo que quiero escribir");
fichero.close();
```

Si teniendo el fichero así, hay alguna forma sencilla de mandarlo a imprimir a una impresora.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/printing
https://es.wikihow.com/imprimir-textos-desde-un-dispositivo-con-Android

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `sockets` para conectarte a la impresora, te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
Socket socket;

try {
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + java.io.File.separator + "fichero.txt"); //Lees el archivo creado.
   InputStream inputStream = fileInputStream;

   socket = new Socket("IP Impresora", "PUERTO"); //Agregas IP y Puerto
   dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

   byte[] buffer = new byte[3000];

   while (inputStream.read(buffer) !=-1){
      dataOutputStream.write(buffer);
   }

   dataOutputStream.flush();

}catch (ConnectException connectException){
   Log.e(TAG, connectException.toString(), connectException);
}
```